# Remove all hyperlinks of a Google Slide using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I am trying to remove all hyperlinks of the slide.

Below is the code I have tried but that doesnt work. Can you tell me where I have gone wrong?

```
function run()
{
var ppt = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
var slide = ppt.getSlides()[0];

var pe  = slide.getPageElements();

var startOffset = pe[0].asShape().getText().getLinks()[0].getStartIndex();
var endOffset = pe[0].asShape().getText().getLinks()[0].getEndIndex();
pe[0].asShape().getText().getRange(startOffset, endOffset).getTextStyle().setLinkUrl(null)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- Q1. You want to know the reason of the issue of your script.
- Q2. You want to delete all hyperlinks in a slide in a Google Slides using Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer?

### A1:

In your script, `setLinkUrl(null)` is used for deleting the link. This is the reason of your issue. In this case, please use `removeLink()` instead of `setLinkUrl(null)`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style#removelink)

### A2:

In your script, you try to delete the 1st hyperlink of the text in the 1st shape on the 1st page. This is the reason of your issue. In order to delete all hyperlinks in a slide in a Google Slides, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const slides = SlidesApp.openById("###").getSlides();  // Please set the Slides ID.

  const otherTypes = {"IMAGE": "asImage", "LINE": "asLine", "SHEETS_CHART": "asSheetsChart", "WORD_ART": "asWordArt"};
  const slide = slides[0];
  slide.getPageElements().forEach(e => {
    const type = e.getPageElementType();
    if (type == SlidesApp.PageElementType.SHAPE) {
      const shape = e.asShape();
      shape.removeLink();
      shape.getText().getLinks().forEach(l => l.getTextStyle().removeLink());
    } else if (type == SlidesApp.PageElementType.TABLE) {
      const table = e.asTable();
      const rows = table.getNumRows();
      const cols = table.getNumColumns();
      for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (let c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
          table.getCell(r, c).getText().getLinks().forEach(l => l.getTextStyle().removeLink());
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (type in otherTypes) e[otherTypes[type]]().removeLink();
    }
  });
}
```

- If you use the container-bound script of the Google Slides, you can also use `SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()` instead of `const slides = SlidesApp.openById("###").getSlides()`.
- In this sample script, all hyperlinks of all texts and of all objects in the 1st slide in the Google Slides are deleted. The texts in the shape and tables are deleted.

### Note:

- Please use this script with V8.
- If you want to delete all hyperlinks in all slides in a Google Slides, you can use the following script.

  ```
  function myFunction() {
    const slides = SlidesApp.openById("###").getSlides();  // Please set the Slides ID.

    const otherTypes = {"IMAGE": "asImage", "LINE": "asLine", "SHEETS_CHART": "asSheetsChart", "WORD_ART": "asWordArt"};
    slides.forEach(s => {
      s.getPageElements().forEach(e => {
        const type = e.getPageElementType();
        if (type == SlidesApp.PageElementType.SHAPE) {
          const shape = e.asShape();
          shape.removeLink();
          shape.getText().getLinks().forEach(l => l.getTextStyle().removeLink());
        } else if (type == SlidesApp.PageElementType.TABLE) {
          const table = e.asTable();
          const rows = table.getNumRows();
          const cols = table.getNumColumns();
          for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (let c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
              table.getCell(r, c).getText().getLinks().forEach(l => l.getTextStyle().removeLink());
            }
          }
        } else {
          if (type in otherTypes) e[otherTypes[type]]().removeLink();
        }
      });
    });
  }
  ```

### References:

- [removeLink() in Class Shape](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#removelink)
- [removeLink() in Class TextStyle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style#removelink)